# How Use instanceof operator with abstract class?

Tags: php, oop, interface, abstract-class, instanceof

How Can I use **instanceof** operator with these 3 child class that extends abstract class?

> When I instantiate all them it outputs result with only one product - **Book**
>   Specific data.  With Other 2 products (**Disc, Furniture**) doesn't display specific data and doesn't add data to SQL Data Base too.

I want use this code with instanceof operator in index.php (instead of code down), But it doest't work correctly.

```
function show($user) {
    if($user instanceof HavingWeight)
    {
      $user->setWeight($weight);
    } elseif ($user instanceof HavingSize)
    {
      $user->setSize($size);
    } elseif($user instanceof HavingFur_dims)
    {
      $user->setHeight($height);
      $user->setWidth($width);
      $user->setLength($length);
    } else 
    { 
      die("This is not a Product..");
    }
}

show(new Book);
show(new Disc);
show(new Furniture);
```

---

**index.php**

```
$user = new Book();
$Size = new Disc();
$Fur = new Furniture();

$user->setWeight($weight);    
$Size->setSize($size);    
$Fur->setHeight($height);    
$Fur->setWidth($width);    
$Fur->setLength($length);
```

**Product.php**

```
abstract class Product
{
  // All common properties and methods
}
```

**Book.php**

```
<?php 

// interfaces
interface HavingWeight
{
    public function setWeight($weight);
}

// traits
trait WithWeight
{
    // setters
    public function setWeight($weight)
    {
        $this->weight = $weight;
    }
}

// Child classes
class Book extends Product implements HavingWeight
{
   use WithWeight;
}

?>
```

**Furniture.php**

```
<?php 
include_once 'classes/Product.php'; 

// interfaces of each product type
interface HavingFur_dims
{
    public function setHeight($height);
    public function setWidth($width);
    public function setLength($length);
}

// traits of each product type
trait WithFur_dims
{
    // setters
    public function setHeight($height)
    {
        return $this->height = $height;
    }

    public function setWidth($width)
    {
        return $this->width = $width;
    }

    public function setLength($length)
    {
        return $this->length = $length;
    }
}

// Child classes
class Furniture extends Product implements HavingFur_dims
{
   use WithFur_dims;
}

?>
```

**Disc.php**

```
<?php 

// interfaces of each product type
interface HavingSize
{
    public function setSize($size);
}

// traits of each product type
trait WithSize
{
    // setters    
    public function setSize($size)
    {
        $this->size = $size;
    }
}

// Child classes
class Disc extends Product implements HavingSize
{
   use WithSize;
}

?>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What problem? You are not using `instanceof` anywhere. What are you trying to do and where exactly? You are also not outputting anything nor are you doing any database operations...

Comment: @jeroen main idea is  to create an abstract class with all product common logic, like getTitle, setTitle etc. Then create child product classes for each product type to store product type specific logic like furniture sizes, CD size, book weight et.. For this requirement I use traits and interfaces. But when I instantiate all child classes in **index.php** it outputs only one Product specfic data **(Book Weight)**. I want to output all them. I think it wiil helps **instanceof** operator to solve this problem. but I don't know how use it. Could u help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not create an instance of an abstract class, because you get a fatal error.

But you can use instanceOf abstractClass to see if the derived class extends your abstract class.

```
abstract class Product
{
  // All common properties and methods
}

class ProductEx1 extends Product{}


$inst = new ProductEx1;
if($inst instanceOf Product){
  echo "Yes, ProductEx1 is also a instance of Product";
}
```